# How to set an <option> element's class attribute via KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I have HTML `select` element being populated via a KnockoutJS viewmodel like so:

```
<select data-bind="options: $data.answers,  optionsText: function(item) { return item.text }, value: selectedAnswer, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

What I would like to do is set the `class` attribute of each `option` element by some means, so that I end up with:

```
<option class="someValue">12345</option>
```

Can this be done in KnockoutJS? I'm having difficulty in finding a solution for this.

EDIT:

I've just tried the `foreach` binding, as suggested by Artem and it is very close to working as I want. But there is one issue.

On the `Question` object there is a function which subscribes to the `SelectedAnswer` observable:

`this.selectedAnswer.subscribe(function (answer) {}`

When I use the `foreach` binding, the `subscribe()` fires off, once for each question (it shouldn't fire until I've chosen an answer. I think this is because the "Choose..." option is now not shown).

For the `foreach` binding, how can I set the default text back to "Choose..." and stop the `selectedAnswer.subscribe()` from firing until the user has chosen an item, and not when the list is being populated.

EDIT:

OK here's how I've done this.

In the KO viewmodel class I have a boolean `bindingFinished` which I check inside of `selectedAnswer.subscribe()`. If `false` then we just return from the function; if true then carry on as normal.

Also I add a default "Choose" option to the answers by adding a new `Answer` to the beginning of the array. The end result is that the subscribe function is not executed when the data is being bound, only after the user has chosen an option.

Many thanks to Artem for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `foreach` binding instead of `options` in the `select` tag:

```
<select data-bind="value: selectedAnswer">
    <option class="someValue">Choose...</option>
    <!-- ko foreach: $data.answers -->
    <option class="someValue" data-bind="value: $data, text: text"></option>
    <!-- /ko -->
</select>
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/5bPWQ/1/

Comment: Having weird behaviors with this, seems that the selected value isn't binding correctly

Comment: I just ran into an issue with something similar to this so just be aware that using comments within a select menu doesnt work in IE9... https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/578

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with the [`optionsAfterRender`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html#note-2-post-processing-the-generated-options) binding.
It will invoke the provided function for each `option` element it generated.
All you have to do is add the class to the element.

**Example:**

**HTML**:

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="options: list, 
        optionsAfterRender: addOptionClass"></select>
```

**JS**:

```
this.addOptionClass = function(optionElement) {
    optionElement.classList.add("form-control");
};
```

Comment: This is the correct answer inline with the proper way it should be done, supported by docs.

Answer (score 0):

For me, code using the chosen value (selectedAnswer) gave an error after applying this fix. I fixed this by adding `value=""` to the default option (Choose...).

Answer (score 0):

Based in previous answers, I just found another way to do it

```
   <select data-bind="foreach: yourArray">
     <option data-bind="value: IdValue, text: TextValue, attr: { customAttr: anyValueField }"></option>
   </select>
```

It Works for me. I Hope it helps for others